# How to import an useState object from another folder

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I have a project which created in "Creat React App" and i have an useState array which looks like this:

```js
const [State, setState] = useState([]);
```

This array is in another folder inside a component called `StateComp`, but i also want to load this array in the main folder (`App.js` for this case).

I tried to just import the `State` and the `setState` from the `StateComp` file into the `App.js` file, but as i expected, the import itself failed.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Trying to export values from the tuple returned by `useState` (e.g. `state`/`setState`) for use in an `import` statement in another module would be an antipattern in React. What problem are you trying to solve that you think you need to import the array managed by React's state?

Comment: i need to make a live component which supposed to run a ```map``` function on the ```useState``` array and create certain type of components that are gonna have the data from this ``` useState``` array. it supposed to look like this: ``` {State.map(e => 
          <Polygon color={"blue"} positions={someDataManipulation(e)}></Polygon>)} ``` Be aware that ```<Polygon>``` is the component type of the components that are going to be formed and take their data from the array. The ```State``` is the ```useState`` array

Comment: Now that you have started to describe the real problem, you should include all of that information in your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72048183/edit) it. You should also include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), explaining where the error/problem occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [React Context](https://medium.com/@danfyfe/using-react-context-with-functional-components-153cbd9ba214) to manage this or [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/). Here's an example with React Context:

`src/providers/StateProvider.js`

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";

import { createContext } from "react";

const StateContext = createContext({
  state: [],
  setState: () => {},
});

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext);

const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default StateProvider;
```

`src/App.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import { useStateProvider } from "./providers/StateProvider";

export default App = () => {
  const { state, setState } = useStateProvider();

  return <h1>MyApp</h1>;
};
```

`src/index.js`

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import StateProvider from "./providers/StateProvider";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider>
      <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: i tried to do it but it got a little complicated and didn't work, but i also saw that there's a library called Recoil and the way it solved problems like this was actually a bit similar. Is that what you actually did here?

Comment: Nope, I just used React Context, but any library that can manage states should work, this is just to not install a third-party library to manage the states as you try to do, maybe in bigger projects you can another library to do that like Recoil or Redux, but for small projects or testing this should work. Why did it get complicated?

Comment: it got comlicated because it says that the ```<StateProvider>``` component that you've mentioned in the ```index.js``` having some sort of problem with other components and stuff that i have in the project, so i tried to change it and it didn't work at all, so i have to think about something else. But even if it didn't work, at least you gave me the idea that Recoil is probably the best solution for my case

Comment: **FOR FUTURE VIEWERS: THIS ANSWER ACTUALLY TURNED OUT TO BE THE ALMOST COMPLETLEY WHAT I NEEDED (with a few changes), SO I MARKED IT AS THE CORRECT ANSWER.**
I personally used the Recoil library, but it works almost the same, and this answer gave me the idea about how it supposed to work. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom hooks for this! You can see an example of this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72048200/8222441 and an example of it being called in another file here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72048200/8222441

Here is a quick solution to help in the meantime:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useSomeState(someParam) {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // do some state logic here if you want
  });

  return { someState, setSomeState };
}

// in another file...

import { useSomeState } from './useSomeStateFile.js'

function SomeComponent = () => {
   const { someState, setSomeState } = useSomeState(someParam)
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help. second thing, i didn't really get the idea of your quick solution. Do you actually mean that i need to create a folder specifically for the ```useState``` array instead of building it in the folder that i originaly set it?

Comment: Hey Mike, you can put the first portion of the code in one file called useSomeStateFile.js (for explanatory purposes of course) and then in another file where you want to use that state, you can import it as shown in the bottom portion of the code. You can't share the same state between more than 1 component, but you can certainly access state through a custom hook, which is what my solution alludes.

Comment: well, that's a really nice idea, but as you've mentioned, i can't use it in more the two components, which is exactly my problem here: creating a ```state``` array, using it in the same component as well as in some other components

Comment: You can create this custom hook elsewhere and call it in both files so that it can be used in more than 1 component at the same time.

Comment: oh ok, that's a good idea. thanks again! i'll definitely try it